# when i want to redirect from http to https its send to an other website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, ubuntu-14.04

When i want to redirect from http to https it's redirect me to an other website on the same server 
this is my first website : https://www.linaktob.com
the second website : https://www.fevrok.com

when i login to the first website from https OR 443 works fine 
but when i login from http OR port 80 it's redirect to the second website

this is my apache configuration for the first website :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName linaktob.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/linaktob.com/public
Redirect permanent / https://www.linaktob.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin  admin@linaktob.com
ServerName   linaktob.com
ServerAlias  www.linaktob.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/linaktob.com/public/

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile     /etc/ssl/linaktob/www.linaktob.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/ssl/linaktob/www.linaktob.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/linaktob/www.linaktob.com.ca-bundle

ErrorLog /var/www/linaktob.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/linaktob.com/logs/access.log combined
<Directory /var/www/linaktob.com/public/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're visting `http://linaktob.com:80` and not `http://www.linkatob.com:80`? Because your VirtualHost on port 80 does not contain a ServerAlias for the `www` subdomain

Comment: thanks the problem caused because i didn't add the server aliad to port 80 @JohannesH.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it and this quesition is shown solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VirtualHost` for port `80` is missing a `ServerAlias www.linkatob.com`.

Because of this, `http://www.linkatob.com/:80` will not be served by this `VirtualHost` but by the default entry - which appears to be your other website.

Add the `VirtualHost` and you're good.